# Get drop down list options based on selected checkbox value

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the following codes that generate checkboxes from database

```html
< table class="table">
  < thead>
    < /thead>
      < th>
        <?php
           $oaNamesQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT oaName FROM oaDetails";
            $oaNamesQueryExecute = mysqli_query($conn, $oaNamesQuery);
             while($oaNamesQueryRow = mysqli_fetch_array($oaNamesQueryExecute)){
                   $oaName = $oaNamesQueryRow['oaName'];
                   echo '<div class = "checkbox-group" required style="float:left; margin-right: 25px;">                          <input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" id="checkBoxArray"             name="checkBoxArray[]" value="'.$oaName.'"> '.$oaName.'</div>';
                        }
                    ?>
          < /th>
            < /table>
```

There is another input box as below whereby input type is number

```html
<div class="col-sm">
  <label for="numberOfShiftPerDay">Number</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numberOfShiftPerDay" name="numberOfShiftPerDay" placeholder="No: " onchange="disablingRoutine()" min="1" max="4">
</div>
```

Example UI as below

[image]

When I enter some number, there will be a drop down menu appear according to the number I entered. Eg: If keyed in 1, there will be one drop down list will appear as below using jQuery 'OnChange'. The UI will be as below

[image]

**What I Need**

I need the drop down menu options to be based on user selected checkboxes. Eg: If the user selected checkboxes X, Y and XX, then these drop down list should show X, Y and XX. Can someone help me how to do this?

**Edit 1**

Added Javascript function on the change routine as suggested by stackoverflow member. But now having duplicate issues. Below the code that I changed

```js
if ($("#numberOfShiftPerDay").val() == 1) {
  $.each($("input[name='checkBoxArray[]']:checked"), function() {
    cval = $(this).val();
    $('#oaInShift1').append('<option>' + cval + '</option>')
  });
} else if ($("#numberOfShiftPerDay").val() == 2) {
  $.each($("input[name='checkBoxArray[]']:checked"), function() {
    cval = $(this).val();
    $('#oaInShift2').append('<option>' + cval + '</option>')
  });
} else if ($("#numberOfShiftPerDay").val() == 3) {
  $.each($("input[name='checkBoxArray[]']:checked"), function() {
    cval = $(this).val();
    $('#oaInShift3').append('<option>' + cval + '</option>')
  });
} else {
  $.each($("input[name='checkBoxArray[]']:checked"), function() {
    cval = $(this).val();
    $('#oaInShift4').append('<option>' + cval + '</option>')
  });
}
```

Comment: You have to use [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: I am not getting any data from server side to show the options in the drop down list. So why do I need to use Ajax? Is this able to do using just JQuery?

Comment: Ah sorry yes it is I just wasnt sure what did you want to do

Comment: You can check the condition by checking which checkbox are checked and populate the dropdown you can refer [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-DropDownList-from-JSON-Array-using-jQuery.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the selected checkbox values and append to your dropdown list in your `onchange` function.

**Try this:**

```
function disablingRoutine()
{
    $.each($("input[name='checkBoxArray[]']:checked"), function(){
        cval = $(this).val();
        $('#dropdownID').append('<option>'+cval+'</option>')

    });    
}
```

**Edit 2**

```
function disablingRoutine()
{
    cdata = '';
    $.each($("input[name='checkBoxArray[]']:checked"), function(){
        cval = $(this).val();
        cdata += '<option>'+cval+'</option>';
    }); 
    $('#dropdownID').html(cdata)   
}
```

Comment: First of all, the drop down list is a dynamically created one by using php loops based on the number keyed in. So the id is not a fixed. However, I tried your code with static drop down list. But somehow it is not working

Comment: @Anu, I edited my code.  checkbox name wrong previously. Try now.

Comment: I should say it is working partially. Because currently there are two problems. 1. If user keep on changing the value, options are adding multiple times. 2. If user first change the number and then click checkboxes, drop down list is not populating. I updated my question with current code from you to see how it is working
Can you give me some suggestions about how to solve those?

Comment: @Anu Instead of append() try html(). It will resolve duplicates issue. Updated ans check

Comment: Perfect answer. I also did some tricks to tackle the other problem that I mentioned when user change the number first and then click checkboxes